# Having trouble converting paths in Pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.7, pathlib

I have to take in a file path that looks like this:

```
'C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test_folder'
```

It gets stored into a variable as a string so:

```
path_intake = 'C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test_folder'
```

I want to assign that path to my

```
p = Path(path_intake)
```

But, When `p` takes in `path_intake` it changes the path to:

```
'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test_folder'
```

Which is not what I want since `.rglob` can only read the path like this:

```
p = Path(C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test_folder)
```

How to obtain this path by taking in the first path?

Comment: what is your exact pattern & expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The value

```
C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test_folder
```

is not a canonical Windows path string. As everyone knows, Windows uses backslashes. So if you supply `/`, `pathlib` turns the path into a canonical path string for your platform, which is

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test_folder
```

But the two `Path` objects are identical, as you will quickly see if you do this:

```
>>> p = pathlib.Path(r"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test_folder")     
>>> p2 = pathlib.Path(r"C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test_folder")     
>>> p == p2     
True
```

You are not correct when you say that "`.rglob` can only read a path like this: `C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test_folder`". To demonstrate that, do this:

```
>>> list(p.rglob("*.txt")) == list(p2.rglob("*.txt"))
True
```

The `Path` objects are identical and you can call `.rglob()` on either one and get the expected result.